# UINavigationController not popping a view when back button pressed, but navigation bar animates

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm creating a very simple sample app to show how preferences will work with a new application I'm working on. The process is very simple: create a UINavigationController in IB, assign it the View Controller that will be the root view controller, and push a new view controller onto the navigation controller's stack when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called.

I've read as many related topics to this as I can find and never found a satisfactory answer.

The problem is that when the back button is pressed, the navigation controller animates back, but the view itself doesn't change back, meaning it's not getting popped.

This is the code I use to push the new view controller onto the stack. It's pretty standard. I added the NSLog to make sure it's only getting hit once.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.section != 0)
    return;

NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath\n");

PrefsListTableViewController *prefsListTableViewController = [[PrefsListTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PrefsListTableViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:prefsListTableViewController animated:YES];
[prefsListTableViewController release];
}
```

To check if the viewWillDisappear call is hit on the second view, I added this to my PrefsListTableViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
NSLog(@"ptvc viewWillDisappear");
}
```

This never gets hit.

First, I was under the impression that you don't need to code anything to handle the back button since the UINavigationController should pop the stack for you automatically when you press the back button. I can show that with a sample app I have which does what I'm doing, but the sample is code only. The code is from Erica Sadun's iPhone Developer's Cookbook code, recipe 11-11. Her code is here:

https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C11-Tables/11-Disclosure%20Chevrons

If you look at her code, there are no .xib files, and everything is handled without the need to code the back button at all. The view controllers are pushed in code, and popped, seemingly, without code. I prefer to use .xib files and everything SHOULD be working the same way, but it's not.

Second, I put in NSLog statements to show that in fact, the root navigation controller has the two view controllers.

```
2011-11-18 11:14:36.355 TableViewTest[58011:207] didSelectRowAtIndexPath
2011-11-18 11:14:36.358 TableViewTest[58011:207] ptvc viewWillAppear (
"<TableViewController: 0x8923d40>",
"<PrefsListTableViewController: 0x8927a20>"
)
2011-11-18 11:14:36.717 TableViewTest[58011:207] ptvc viewDidAppear (
"<TableViewController: 0x8923d40>",
"<PrefsListTableViewController: 0x8927a20>"
)
```

So you can see that the view controllers are pushed and in the proper order.

That leads to one question: why isn't PrefsListTableViewController getting popped when the back button is pressed? If anyone needs any more info, please let me know.

Comment: I would recommend using the xCode templates, or to start with example code from the iOS Developer Center.  The code you linked is very much outdated - apparently targeted for 3.0, but is using methods like applicationDidFinishLaunching:.  Documentation says "In iOS 3.0 and later, you should use the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: instead.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Jacob, I believe you're looking at Erica's example, not my code. We're targeting iOS 4.2. The sample code was there to show that code wasn't necessary to handle the back button.

Comment: When you hit the back button, the popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated is called on the UINavigationBar, which in turn calls popViewControllerAnimated on the navigation controller.  The behavior seems to indicate that the second call is unsuccessful.  Do you have any subclasses or categories on UINavigationController that may be intercepting the popViewControllerAnimated call?

Comment: Jacob, None. The UINavigationController is placed into the MainWindow.xib as is, so subclassing is done at all.

Comment: I figured it out. The delegate had a referencing outlet called "delegate" which was linked to TWO outlets. It should just be linked to "File's Owner". Fixed.

Comment: Michael - I seem to have encountered a similar problem. Where would I look for the problematic delegate referencing outlet

Answer (score 0):

Have you extended UINavigationController Class? I did and had the same issue. Apparently, according to apple docs, your not supposed to extend that class...

Comment: I have extended UINavigationController, but getting rid of it didn't help. In fact, Apple says explicitly in https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller : "You generally use this class as-is but you may also subclass to customize the class behavior."